# Nslookup doesn't show full info on CentOS 7 docker image

Tags: centos, dns, docker, nslookup

I'm using https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/ **CentOS 7 docker image**.
I created service with 3 replicas inside cluster and i'd like to query internal docker dns.

For **BusyBox image** **nslookup** works exactly in the same way as shown in documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/networking/#/use-swarm-mode-service-discovery):

```
nslookup tasks.my-web

Server:    127.0.0.11
Address 1: 127.0.0.11

Name:      tasks.my-web
Address 1: 10.0.0.8 my-web.2.2s1t73cy4m5oi4nadqjrsp0y9.cluster_net
Address 2: 10.0.0.9 my-web.3.2vu4qaxm5zkz56atmmvlm7iur.cluster_net
Address 3: 10.0.0.7 my-web.1.5dtqm90o8b4vgrli3z81axmyp.cluster_net
```

But with **nslookup** tool (packages: bind-libs-9.9.4-29.el7_2.4.x86_64, bind-utils-9.9.4-29.el7_2.4.x86_64)
 in **CentOS 7 container** I get a truncated result:

```
nslookup tasks.my-web

Server:         127.0.0.11
Address:        127.0.0.11#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   tasks.my-web
Address: 10.0.0.9
Name:   tasks.my-web
Address: 10.0.0.7
Name:   tasks.my-web
Address: 10.0.0.8
```

I'd like to fix this.

**UPD:** I can get additional information using commands

```
nslookup 10.0.0.7
nslookup 10.0.0.8
nslookup 10.0.0.9
```

But I'm interested in more simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Only one-liner solution

```
dig +short tasks.$SERVICE_NAME | xargs -r -n 1 dig +short -x
```

Output

```
my-web.2.2s1t73cy4m5oi4nadqjrsp0y9.cluster_net
my-web.3.2vu4qaxm5zkz56atmmvlm7iur.cluster_net
my-web.1.5dtqm90o8b4vgrli3z81axmyp.cluster_net
```